# How to run script on Tomcat startup?

Tags: shell, tomcat

I would like to know how to run a shell script on Tomcat startup, that is when catalina.log prints "INFO: Server startup in xxx ms"

Thanks in advance, bye

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: No I don't.
@Stefan because I would like to send a message (I'm using Slack but it could be an email too) to rest of the team notifying that the server is up and running

Answer (score 3):

At Tomcat 7, you can accomplish that through a custom listener in the server.xml file at tomcat's configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="your.domain.CustomEventHookListener" />

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="default">
      <Host name="default" 
            appBase="webapps" 
            unpackWARs="false" 
            autoDeploy="false">
        <Context path="" docBase="/opt/www/application">
        </Context>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

CustomEventHootListener.java:

```
package your.domain;

import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;

public class CustomEventHookListener implements LifecycleListener {
  @Override
  public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent arg0) {
    Lifecycle lifecycle = arg0.getLifecycle();
    if (lifecycle == null) {
      return;
    }
    String type = arg0.getType();
    if (type == null) {
      return;
    }
    String stateName = lifecycle.getStateName();
    if (stateName == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (type.equals("after_start") && stateName.equals("STARTED")) {
      startPostInitScript();
    }
  }

  private void startPostInitScript() {
    // Non-blocking please.
    Thread t = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          super.run();
          String script = "/path/to/your-script.sh";
          // inheritIO to output things to JVM.
          new ProcessBuilder().command(script).inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
  }
}
```

You can see a functional example at https://github.com/Valemobi/tomcat-events-hook

Comment: Good answer, but it would be helpful to include a little more detail. It looks like the library you linked is a good start, but describing what it does and how to use it would make the answer more helpful, especially if the repo ever goes down.

Comment: For anyone else looking for details on the Tomcat Lifecycle Events: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

find tomcat startup script (in `/etc/init.d/` maybe `tomcat7`) and write call-to-your-script in appropriate place at `start` block.

Comment: I'm not interested in when Tomcat is starting but when it is up and running, there is a big difference