# Tomcat custom library jar file in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, tomcat

As per this question I have created a class that implements the Catalina LifecycleListener class.

[How to run script on Tomcat startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096312/how-to-run-script-on-tomcat-startup#39281042)

When I place my JAR file in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib, Tomcat fails to startup with a class not found exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.company.tomcat.StartupEventHookListener

But when I place the file in appserver/lib it starts up and then runs the code as expected, when the app has finished starting.

My understanding is that all JAR files in the WEB-INF/lib are available to my webapp (ROOT), and I am trying to hook into the event lifecycle for my webapp.

Am I actually hooking into Tomcat's lifecycle, hence I need to use the appserver/lib library?

Did I just answer my own question?

Comment: Yes you did answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat startup happens before any webapps are launched, even the ROOT webapp. And the classpath used for things configured in the Tomcat lifecycle never includes any jar files or `.class` files from any webapp, even the ROOT webapp.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's a bit confusing, as i'm actually hooking into state of the ROOT webapp. But it makes a bit more sense now.