# How can I let Tomcat run a command after it finishes deploying web application's .war files

Tags: deployment, configuration, log4j, tomcat7

We know that during Tomcat startup, it will deploy the .war files of its web applications. My question is after the deployment I need to run a command to modify a file inside WEB-INF/ of the web application which is generated after deployment, and I need to let Tomcat do this automatically for me, is this possible to achieve ? Something like post_run command after deployment.

I found that CustomEventHookListener can probably do this [How to run script on Tomcat startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096312/how-to-run-script-on-tomcat-startup), but this involves in making a new Java class, and I'm not allowed to do so. I have to figure out way to modify the existing Tomcat configs like server.xml or tomcat.conf in TOMCAT_HOME/conf to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue about not using a Event Hook Listener is that there's no reliable way to tell if the application is ready or not, as Catalina implements it's own lifecycle for each of their components (as seen in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html).

Your best shot is to use tail or some external program infer the component's state, but AFAIK there's no way to implement listeners directly in the configuration files.